# Why do some const variables referring to some exported const variables get the value 0?

Tags: c++, initialization, constants, double, extern

Consider the following. I have two exported constants as follows:

```
// somefile.h
extern const double cMyConstDouble;
extern const double cMyConstDouble2;
```

and

```
// somefile.cpp
const double cMyConstDouble = 3.14;
const double cMyConstDouble2 = 2.5*cMyConstDouble;
```

These constants are now referenced some place else to define two static (locally visible) constants:

```
// someotherfile.cpp
#include "somefile.h"
static const double cAnotherDouble = 1.1*cMyConstDouble;
static const double cAnotherDouble2 = 1.1*cMyConstDouble2;
printf("cAnotherDouble = %g, cAnotherDouble2 = %g\n",
       cAnotherDouble, cAnotherDouble2);
```

Which yields the following output:

```
cAnotherDouble = 3.454, cAnotherDouble2 = 0
```

Why is the second double 0? I'm using .NET 2003 C++ compiler (13.10.3077).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because cMyConstDouble is declared as extern, compiler is not able to assume its value and does not generate a compile time initialization for cMyConstDouble2. As the cMyConstDouble2 is not compile time initialized, its order of initialization relative to cAnotherDouble2 is random (undefined). See [static initialization fiasco](http://www.parashift.com/c%2B%2B-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.12) for more information.

Comment: @Suma: If the `cMyConstDouble2` is not constant folded due to `cMyConstDouble` being `extern` shouldn't the same happen to `cAnotherDouble`? This too depends on `cMyConstDouble` right? How come it's value is printed rightly as 3.454

Comment: Order of initialization across modules is undefined. In one case it was already done, in the second not.

Answer (score 9):

I'm not going to dip my toe into the issues of extern here, but why do you simply not place the consts in the appropriate header files and forget about "exporting" them using extern? This is how consts are supposed to be used in C++, and why they have internal linkage.

In other words:

```
// someheader.h
const double cMyConstDouble = 3.14;
const double cMyConstDouble2 = 2.5*cMyConstDouble;
```

and #include that file wherever you need them.

Comment: So, you *are* dipping your toe in then? :-) +1 anyway.

Comment: Not really - my solution doesn't use extern.

Comment: Actually there is a reason why. We moved from your way to this way, because they caused enormous linking times.

Comment: Then there is something wrong with the architecture of your codebase. All the C++ code I have written and reviewed for the past decade uses my way of doing it with absolutely no problems.

Comment: I'm definitely going to consider your opinions. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @Neil, definitely, i would use that way too. +1 :)

Comment: Also, using "extern const" on integral types will force C-style linkage, which is probably  not desired.

Answer (score 3):

This is dangerous thing to do as your one static variable in one source file depends upon the another static variable in another cpp file. Check [static initialization fiasco](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.12) for more information.

Comment: It is dangerous in general, but this does not apply when compile time initialization by constant takes place. My answer points to the fact that while the code may look like compile time initialization, in fact it is not because of extern.

Answer (score 2):

If you change the initialization of `cMyConstDouble2` to this here:

```
const double cMyConstDouble2 = 2.5*3.14;
```

Then your program should behave correct. The reason for this is that variables that

- Have POD type
- Are initialized with constant expressions *(1)*

are initialized at static initialization time. These initializations include

- Zero initialization of *all* objects having static storage duration
- Initializations of PODs initialized with constant expressions

Of your shown variables, only `cMyConstDouble` satisfies both conditions of being fully initialized at static initialization time. However, `cMyConstDouble2` does not, since its initializer does not satisfy the requirements of a constant expression. In particular, it includes a variable that doesn't have integral type (here, it has floating point type). However, floating point *literals* *are* allowed in arithmetic constant expressions. That is why `2.5*3.14` is an arithmetic constant expression. And that is why changing the initializer to that will require it to be statically initialized.

---

What will happen with `cMyConstDouble2` if you stay with the non-constant expression? The answer is, you don't know. The Standard allows that variable to be statically initialized, but does not require it to do so. In your case, it was dynamically initialized - thus its value just after static initialization time was still zero. To get a feeling for how *complicated* that is, here is an example:

```
inline double fd() { return 1.0; }
extern double d1;
double d2 = d1; // unspecified:
                // may be statically initialized to 0.0 or
                // dynamically initialized to 1.0
double d1 = fd(); // may be initialized statically to 1.0
```

If the dynamic initialization doesn't change any other static storage variable (satisfied in *your* code) and when the static initialization would produce the same value as would be produced by dynamic initialization when all objects not required to be statically initialized would be initialized dynamically (also satisfied in *your* code) - then the variable is allowed to be initialized statically. These two conditions are also satisfied in the above code for both variables `d2` and `d1`:

Analysis of `d2`

- `= d1` does not change any other static storage variable
- When both `d2` and `d1` are initialized dynamically, then `d2` would be initialized to `0.0`, because `d2` is defined before `d1`, and dynamic initialization of `d2` would grab the value of `d1` as of the state just after static initialization (where only zero initialization of `d1` took place).

Analysis of `d1`

- `= fd()` does not change any other static storage variable
- When both `d2` and `d1` are initialized dynamically, then `= fd()` will initialize `d1` to `1.0`.

So, the compiler may initialize `d1` statically to `1.0`, because both conditions for optional-static-initialization are met.

- *If* the compiler decides to initialize `d1` and `d2` dynamically, then **`d2` will be initialized to `0.0`**, since it will grab the value of `d1` as it was just after zero initialization.
- *However*, *if* the compiler decides to initialize `d1` statically and `d2` dynamically, then **`d2` will be initialized to `1.0`**, since the dynamic initialization of `d2` will grab the fully initialized value of `d1` as it was just after static initialization.

I'm not sure what the value of `d2` is when `d1` *and* `d2` is initialized statically, though. That is, whether `d2` is supposed to grab the `0.0` or the `1.0`, since there is no order defined for static initialization.

---

*(1)* Constant expressions include arithmetic constant expressions too (not only integral constant expressions), when considering initialization order of objects with static storage duration.